# Why MySQL Database is Bigger After Dump/Import?

Tags: mysql, backup, migration, mysqldump, import

I have 2 VPS and plan to migrate the DB from first to second. The original DB is taking around 15GB of storage and I manage to dump out a 7GB SQL. However, when I imported the SQL to second VPS, it takes up 2x of storage becoming 32GB.

My questions are:

- What might cause my DB from 15GB to become 32GB by just dump+import?
- How can I avoid this?

Below are some further detail:

- Both VPS are not exactly same and so do the MySQL version. The source DB is version 5.5.47. The receiving DB is version 5.7.13.
- The receiving DB is newly install and empty.
- The command I used to dump out SQL is: `mysqldump -u <username> -p --all-databases --add-drop-database --max_allowed_packet=16777216 --single-transaction > full_dump.sql`. The reason I am setting max_allowed_packet is to have the same value compare to receiving DB
- Not sure if this is relevant. If I do not specify `single-transaction` in my mysqldump command, it will error `mysqldump: Got error: 2006: MySQL server has gone away when using LOCK TABLES`
- The source DB storage distribution is different from the receiving DB:

  > 14858M    /var/lib/mysql
  >
  > 14483M    /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
  >
  > 365M  /var/lib/mysql/wordpress
- This is the receiving DB storage distribution:

  > 31558M    /var/lib/mysql
  >
  > 31306M    /var/lib/mysql/wordpress
  >
  > 337M  /var/lib/mysql/wordpress/wp_wfLeechers.ibd
  >
  > 101M  /var/lib/mysql/wordpress/wp_1059_posts.ibd
- I've tried to run table optimisation, but no impact

Comment: What Engine were the tables??  MyISAM?  InnoDB?

Comment: Majority of them are InnoDB, there are some MyISAM though, but not a lot compare to the total number of tables.

Comment: How many tables?  Are any of them `PARTITIONed`?  Many columns `CHAR` as opposed to `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_wfLeechers;` before and after?  Also `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'wp_wfLeechers';`

Comment: Hey thanks for prompt respond. However, I've accepted RonaldoMySQLDBA's answer. After I downgraded MySQL to v5.6, the DB import size is back to normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that caught my eye was the versions of MySQL you are using.

You said

- The source DB is version 5.5.47
- The receiving DB is version 5.7.13

These two versions of MySQL use different default values for innodb_file_format

- [MySQL 5.5 has Antelope as the default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format)
- [MySQL 5.7 has Barracuda as the default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format)

MySQL 5.7 has new ways of storing InnoDB as mentioned in the [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format). Please note:

> The [Barracuda](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_barracuda) file format is required to use Compressed or Dynamic row formats and associated features such as compression, ***off-page storage for large variable-length columns***, and large index key prefixes (see innodb_large_prefix). This restriction does not apply to tables stored in general tablespaces.

If your data has large variable-length columns, the result of reloading could be the storage of data and index info outside of your BTree Indexes and extra splitting of pages. [See DYNAMIC and COMPRESSED Row Formats for more details on this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html). Many of the new InnoDB file format features are deprecated in MySQL 5.7 and will eventually disappear in future releases.

### SUGGESTION #1

Even though deprecated, you could set [innodb_file_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format) to Antelope on the MySQL 5.7 server, restart MySQL, and reload the mysqldump.

### SUGGESTION #2

Use MySQL 5.5/5.6 as the Master instead of MySQL 5.7. Restart MySQL on the Master, and reload mysqldump into the Master.

### SUGGESTION #3

Run `ALTER TABLE innodbtable ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;` on all the MySQL 5.7 InnoDB tables.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 0):

Quite probably the old tables were MyISAM.  (Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` or peek inside the dump.)  And the new tables were forced to be InnoDB.

In the long run this change is good.

A 2x size increase is to be expected in such a change.